# Jquery on click touchstart not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code for when I click in a button, it loads a page inside a div.
I also changed my code to accepting to be working, saw a lot of questions here in the stackoverflow but none of them seems to be working for me in mobile browser.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Jquery Load */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul#nav li a').on('touchstart click', (function() {
                var page = $(this).attr('href');
                $('#lesson').load('ar101/' + page + '.php');
                return false;
            }));
        });
/* End of Jquery Load */
</script>
```

Comment: the touchstart event seems to work just fine for me. This might help - https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/

Comment: It is loading inside a div which has `lesson' id , right ?

Comment: This is loading the information from the selected button (lesson1, lesson2, etc) like in the path: "/ar101/lessonX.php" inside the div with the ID called #lesson.

Works fine for desktop browsers, but on mobile the touch event is not working.

Comment: I have the same problem. I noticed that the problem is only on dinamically added elements like event delegation is not working. Have you find some solution?